# binary search string 2d arrays

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

My question is to find the string in 2d array and if it match display binary no.

Pience of my cide

```
string inst[37][3]={{"ld","00001","C2"},{"st","00011","C2"},{"la","00101","C2"},{"ldr","00010","C1"},
                       {"lar","00110","C1"},{"str","00100","C1"},{"add","01100"," "},{"addi","01101","C2"},
                       {"sub","01110"," "},{"neg","01111"," "},{"or","10110"," "},{"ori","10111","C2"},
                       {"and","10100"," "},{"andi","10101","C2"},{"not","11000"," "},{"shr","11010","C3"},
                       {"shra","11011","C3"},{"shl","11100","C3"},{"shc","11101","C3"},{"br","01000","C3"},
                       {"brl","01001","C3"},{"brlnv","01001"," "},{"brzr","01000"," "},{"brlzr","01001"," "},
                       {"not","11000"," "},{"brnz","01000"," "},{"brlnz","01001"," "},{"brpl","01000"," "},
                       {"brmi","01000"," "},{"brlmi","01001"," "},{"nop","00000"," "},{"stop","11111"," "},
                       {"een","01010"," "},{"edi","01011"," "},{"rfi","11110"," "},{"svi","10000"," "},
                       {"ri","10001"," "}};

int last=36, initial=0 , mid, index;

for(int i = 0; i < icount-1; i++)
        {

            //display arrays
            for(int j = 0; j < 4;j++)
            {

                cout << input[i][j] << "     ";
                // this is for check first column that consist inst and then convert to binary code
                if(j==0)
                {
                        while(last>=initial)
                        {
                           mid=(last+initial)/2;

                           if(input[i][0]==inst[mid][0])
                           {   index=mid;

                           }
                           else if(input[i][0]>inst[mid][0])
                           {   initial=mid+1;
                           }
                           else
                               last=mid-1;
                        }

                        cout<<"   "<<inst[index][1]<<"    ";

                   }
}
```

it's like output not display the correct binary code. Any kind of help I'm really appreciated.
Thanks you.
* I don't want to use return mid and create another function

Comment: That to use the binary search the array must be sorted. I do not see that the array you showed is sorted.

Comment: I don't need the sorted but the idea is that when the user put key for search such as ri ( refer to the first second row) and een ( refer to the third row) compare with the the 2d array that i declare and if it true n then display the binary code which is located at the second column. That's all..

Answer (score 0):

Your search would be soooo much simpler if you reorganized your data:

```
struct Data_Record
{
  string  command;
  string  value;
  string  other;

// Here's what makes the search work better:
  bool operator==(const Data_Record& dr)
  {
    bool is_equal = false;
    if (command == dr.command)
    {
      if (value == dr.value)
      {
         if (other == dr.other)
         {
           is_equal = true;
         }
      }
    }
  }
  bool operator<(const Data_Record& dr)
  {
    return command < dr.command;
  }
};

const Data_Record   inst[37] = { /* ... */};
Data_Record const * p_item_found = NULL;
Data_Record         key = {"and", "", ""};

p_item_found = std::binary_search(&inst[0], &inst[38], key);
if (p_item != &instr[38])
{
  cout << "Found it\n";
}
else
{
  cout << "Item not found.\n";
}
```

You can do other cool stuff like overloading `operator<<` and `operator>>` for custom output and input.

**Edit 1:  OOP hierarchy**
Many instruction sets have groups that share commonality.  For example, jump or branch instructions all have a destination address.  Math instructions may have the same operands.

I recommend having a hierarchy of classes (or structures).  Research "C++ Factory Design Pattern".

```
class Instruction
{
  public:  
    virtual void Print_Annotated(std::ostream& output) = 0;
    virtual void Instruction_Counter Execute(void) = 0;
  protected: 
    std::string opcode;
    std::string instruction_value;
};

class Jump_Instr_Category : public Instruction
{
  protected:  
    unsigned int destination_address;
};

class Math_Instr_Category : public Instruction
{
  protected:
    std::string parameter1;
    std::string parameter2;
};
```

You use the **Factory Pattern** to return a pointer to the `Instruction` base class.

The User's program would be a simple as:

```
std::vector<Instruction *> program;
```

Comment: Actually, I just want make simple coding. The scenario is that when the user enter ri ( refer to the third row ) and een ( refer to the next row) compare with 2d array that just I created just now. Check if it is same value then return that row in 2d array and then I just call that row and column. Eventually, the binary code is display. The error code that i just show you just know is about it can only check the row++ and when the location is behind it can't go back (refer to r--). That's all I need. Thanks you. I'm really appreciate if you not suggest me use vector or stack